# Show dynamic nested dropdown lists in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

I am new to this so please bear with me ..

I have tried different solutions but i don't to get what I need working right. My list of data is read from a JSON file with this code

```
function showInsatserList() {
    var promise = [];
    promise = getSelectedSubareaInsatslist();
    promise.done(function (insatserlist) {
        $('#dropdownmenu li').remove();
        for (var i in insatserlist) {
            $('#dropdownmenu').append('<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">' + insatserlist[i].title + '</a> '
                + '<ul class="dropdown-menu"><li>HEJ</li></ul></li>');
        }
    });
}
```

and then i show it using this ..

```
$('.insatsDropdown').on('click', function (e) {
    showInsatserList();
});
```

now my html look like this ...

```
  <div class="dropdown insatsDropdown">
      <a href="#" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Välj insatser <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul id="dropdownmenu" class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
  </div>
```

What i want to do is that when i click on any of the li from the dropdown menu, it would show only the underlying submenu which at the moment is populated with just a randowm word in swedish "HEJ".

I tried standard click methods but the only thing that would work on dynamic content seems to be by using this line of code below ..

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-submenu', function (e) {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle(); //not working
});
```

the problem is that .. what i do inside does not really toggle anything

my fiddle is here :

https://jsfiddle.net/MissKalani/yvrL24Lv/9/

What i want to do there now is that.. for example.. i click on one of the li.. like "Volvo".. it would show the underlying ul element.

I am open to different approaches too. I tried adding the ul element also when clicking but that does not work either yet for me.

Comment: Did you read the `.next()` doco? It only selects *siblings*, and the ul is not a sibling of the clicked li, it is a child. Browse through [the list of jQuery traversal methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) and I'm sure you'll spot the method you should be using...

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle? That would be help us. I think you should have take a look on the jquery `.first()` function.

Comment: i have set up a fiddle .. in a somewhat similar fashion except for the jsondata.. but now i can't seem to get it working there right either :( sorry https://jsfiddle.net/MissKalani/y959b6jd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add some extra styles (code below) in order to show the nested lists on hover. See https://jsfiddle.net/yvrL24Lv/10/

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

Comment: ah yes. thanks. that is right. now what is lacking here is that.. i wanted to click .. for example Volvo .. and it would show the underlying submenu.. which is not doing so atm :(

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/yvrL24Lv/10/

Comment: Yes yes! that is what i wanted! <3 Damn css! ugh! :) Thanks. I can at least move forward now after several hours being stuck :D

Comment: thanks. quick favor though. what if i wanted to toggle using click instead of hover? when i put in :active. it seems to open it .. but closes the menu as well as soon as i remove the pointer

Comment: @Kalani, that's complicated. I guess you'll have to use javascript/jQuery to -override the default list behavior and add some classes or simulate hover- on click.

Comment: Aight. yeh i was thinking that too. I can continue to mess around with js. thanks again